# wsdl2apex- Generating class

Tags: apex, wsdl2apex

We already have a wsdl2apex class .

A few new fields will be added in the wsdl coming from 3rd party.

Do we need to regenerate the wsdl to apex class again or changes can be done manually ?

Answer (score 2):

They can be added manually, although it can be quite tedious.  I would recommend regenerating the classes if possible.

It is likely to be less error prone.

However, if you've already extended these generated classes you might want to manually add the fields.

Here's more info on [how classes are generated](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_gen_code.htm).